# Simplehtmldom multiple links save

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

So, I'm starting with php and have a trouble with Simple HTML DOM Parser. This is my code so far.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=file_get_html("http://example.com");
foreach($html->find('a') as $links);
$html = file_get_html($links->href);
echo $html;
```

The main problem is that there are $links instead of one page, that are constantly changing and I don't know how to make computer understand me because I end up with errors and total mess. I will really appreciate any response!

Comment: Do you mean there are more than 1 anchor tag on a page?

Comment: Yes, and I want them all to be parsed.

Comment: What do you want to do with all these links?

Answer (score 1):

You need some brackets here instead of a semicolon:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $links) {

    $html = file_get_html($links->href);
    echo $html;
}
```

With the semicolon right after the foreach definition, it won't run anything. If you remove the semicolon, it will still only execute the first line after the loop definition. You need the brackets to group the two statements together.

I don't know how well echoing out the entire HTML for multiple pages in a row will work, though.

Comment: :) beat me to it by milli seconds :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's about the opposite of what usually happens. (Except for the milliseconds part. Usually you've already answered it five minutes ago)

Comment: I didn't say that I want them all in one echo. This works just for one of them.

Comment: @GrzegorzCichocki I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain a bit more, please?

Answer (score 0):

You want `file_get_html` because `file_get_contents` will load the response body into a string but `file_get_html` will load it into simple-html-dom.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=file_get_html("http://example.com");
foreach($html->find('a') as $links) {
   $html = file_get_html($links->href);
   echo $html;
}
```